# xcode 6 copy views from older projects

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, xcode6

I created a new Xcode6 project and things were great.. but then I copies a few view controllers from an old project over. Now those views have an odd black bar appearing at the bottom of the view when I run the app on a device or in the simulator. Its transparent on some devices and not on others. They all have "bottom bar" set to none.

I tested this out by re-creating one of the views and the bar is gone. has anyone run into this before? If so, is there a setting to change to fix it? I have been looking through the source code version of my storyboard and see nothing that will help. Its not any constraints I have set because 1 of the views is nothing but basic tableView with no changes or outlets.

I know the "solution" is to recreate all views I copied over. However, I spent a great deal of time on setting each individual subviews constraints on a particular view controller. So if I am missing some simple setting my time wont be wasted re-setting up this VC.

Thanks for any help given :)
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is because the view doesn't set to fit the screen size, There are couple of things that you can check. 1. in File Inspector > interface Builder Document, tick Use Size Classes. 2. by using [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size to set your view frame correctly. 3. check your view constraints.

Comment: Thanks, Use Size Classes was checked. I un-checked it, canceled the popup message, and left it checked. Cleaned and ran the app. Now its full size ? :) thanks for the input.